# Jetpack Compose TextField trailingIcon causes crash

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, textfield

```
      @Composable
        private fun MyTextField(
            value: String,
            placeholder: String = "",
            onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
            onDone: KeyboardActionScope.() -> Unit,
            keyboardType: KeyboardType = KeyboardType.Ascii,
            modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        ) {
            var text by remember { mutableStateOf(value) }
            val isVisible by remember {
                derivedStateOf {
                    text.isNotBlank()
                }
            }
            val lightBlue = Color(0xffd9e8ff)
            TextField(
                value = value,
                onValueChange = onValueChange,
                placeholder = { Text(placeholder) },
                modifier = modifier,
                trailingIcon = {
                    if (isVisible) {
                        IconButton(
                            onClick = { text = "" }
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Clear,
                                contentDescription = "Clear"
                            )
                        }
                    }
                },
                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                    onDone = onDone
                ),
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                    keyboardType = keyboardType
                ),
                singleLine = true,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.colors(
                    cursorColor = Color.Black,
                    disabledLabelColor = lightBlue,
                    focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
                )
            )
        }
```

5:57:03.377  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't represent a size of 2147483503 in Constraints
at androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints$Companion.bitsNeedForSize(Constraints.kt:403)
at androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints$Companion.createConstraints-Zbe2FdA$ui_unit_release(Constraints.kt:366)
at androidx.compose.ui.unit.ConstraintsKt.Constraints(Constraints.kt:433)
at androidx.compose.ui.unit.ConstraintsKt.Constraints$default(Constraints.kt:418)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeMeasuringIntrinsics.minHeight$ui_release(LayoutModifierNode.kt:198)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNode.minIntrinsicHeight(LayoutModifierNode.kt:90)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.minIntrinsicHeight(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:144)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.SizeNode.minIntrinsicHeight(Size.kt:864)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.minIntrinsicHeight(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:144)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.minIntrinsicHeight(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:782)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldMeasurePolicy$minIntrinsicHeight$1.invoke(TextField.kt:810)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldMeasurePolicy$minIntrinsicHeight$1.invoke(TextField.kt:809)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldMeasurePolicy.intrinsicHeight(TextField.kt:900)
at androidx.compose.material3.TextFieldMeasurePolicy.minIntrinsicHeight(TextField.kt:809)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.IntrinsicsPolicy.minIntrinsicHeight(IntrinsicsPolicy.kt:41)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.minIntrinsicHeight(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:136)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.minIntrinsicHeight(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:782)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.DefaultIntrinsicMeasurable.measure-BRTryo0(Layout.kt:323)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(Box.kt:114)
at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasurePolicy.minIntrinsicHeight(MeasurePolicy.kt:125)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.IntrinsicsPolicy.minIntrinsicHeight(IntrinsicsPolicy.kt:41)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.minIntrinsicHeight(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:136)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.UnspecifiedConstraintsNode.minIntrinsicHeight(Size.kt:1097)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.minIntrinsicHeight(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:144)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeMeasuringIntrinsics$DefaultIntrinsicMeasurable.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNode.kt:264)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.FillNode.measure-3p2s80s(Size.kt:699)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNode$minIntrinsicHeight$1.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifierNode.kt:92)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.NodeMeasuringIntrinsics.minHeight$ui_release(LayoutModifierNode.kt:201)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNode.minIntrinsicHeight(LayoutModifierNode.kt:90)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.minIntrinsicHeight(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:144)
at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$MeasurePassDelegate.minIntrinsicHeight(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:782)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicMeasureBlocks$VerticalMinHeight$1$1.invoke(RowColumnImpl.kt:476)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicMeasureBlocks$VerticalMinHeight$1$1.invoke(RowColumnImpl.kt:474)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt.intrinsicMainAxisSize(RowColumnImpl.kt:566)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt.intrinsicSize(RowColumnImpl.kt:543)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.RowColumnImplKt.access$intrinsicSize(RowColumnImpl.kt:1)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicMeasureBlocks$VerticalMinHeight$1.invoke(RowColumnImpl.kt:474)
at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.IntrinsicMeasureBlocks$VerticalMinHeight$1.invoke(RowColumnImpl.kt:473)

```
compose_version = '1.5.2'
implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
implementation “androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha08"
```